# Encrypt in python 3.7 and decode in NODEJS 12

Tags: python, node.js, encryption

I read a post: encrypted-data-between-node-js-and-python.

I need to implement the reverse path, create the encryption in python and decode in the node.

On the Python side I did:

```
from nacl.secret import SecretBox
from base64 import b64encode
import nacl.secret
import nacl.utils

secret_key = bytes('_THIS_IS_MY_32_CHARS_SECRET_KEY_', 'utf8')
message =  bytes('Some Italians hate wine','utf-8')

nonce = nacl.utils.random(24)

box = SecretBox(secret_key)
encrypted = box.encrypt(message,nonce)
ctext = encrypted.ciphertext
print(ctext)

plaintext = box.decrypt(encrypted)
print(plaintext.decode('utf-8'))

print(b64encode(nonce))
print(b64encode(encrypted
```

In node:

```
const nacl = require('tweetnacl');
const utils = require('tweetnacl-util');
const secretKey = Buffer.from('_THIS_IS_MY_32_CHARS_SECRET_KEY_', 'utf8');
const nonce = utils.decodeBase64('KRmiqOFUN1HklmPZgbd0BINNDDCu3dyB');
      
const encryptedMessage = utils.decodeBase64('KRmiqOFUN1HklmPZgbd0BINNDDCu3dyB/s4tdTjcw65K6Lr5N797+7zoLm9WClCXIDNLAqrNGwF2MybtJu+U');
    
const originalMessage = nacl.secretbox.open(
    encryptedMessage,
    nonce,
    secretKey
);
```

The result was NULL.

What is the correct way to do this integration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`encrypted` returned by [`SecretBox.encrypt()`](https://pynacl.readthedocs.io/en/v0.2.1/secret/#nacl.secret.SecretBox.encrypt) in the *PyNaCl* code is an [`EncryptedMessage`](https://pynacl.readthedocs.io/en/v0.2.1/public/#nacl.utils.EncryptedMessage) object (a `bytes` subclass) that holds the concatenated (24 bytes) nonce and ciphertext. Note that `EncryptedMessage` also has the properties `nonce` and `ciphertext`.

Since the *TweetNaCl* code uses the concatenated (Base64 encoded) data, these data must first be separated (after Base64 decoding) and nonce and ciphertext must be processed separately in [`nacl.secretbox.open()`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tweetnacl#naclsecretboxopenbox-nonce-key). Please note that *TweetNaCl* uses TypedArrays. For the conversion to or from Utf8 or Base64 the functions from *tweetnacl-util* can be used:

```js
const secretKey = nacl.util.decodeUTF8('_THIS_IS_MY_32_CHARS_SECRET_KEY_');
const encryptedMessage = nacl.util.decodeBase64('KRmiqOFUN1HklmPZgbd0BINNDDCu3dyB/s4tdTjcw65K6Lr5N797+7zoLm9WClCXIDNLAqrNGwF2MybtJu+U');

// Separate nonce and ciphertext
const nonce = encryptedMessage.slice(0, 24)
const ciphertext = encryptedMessage.slice(24) 

// Decrypt
const originalMessage = nacl.secretbox.open(ciphertext, nonce, secretKey);

const decryptedText = nacl.util.encodeUTF8(originalMessage);
console.log(decryptedText); // Some Italians hate wine
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tweetnacl-util@0.15.1/nacl-util.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tweetnacl@1.0.3/nacl.min.js"></script>
```

Please note that this snippet is pure JavaScript. In your NodeJS environment you have to replace `nacl.util` with `utils`.

Comment: Excellent code and explanation. I'm looking how to go the other direction (encryption in JS and decryption in python): will let you know what I find!