# Encrypt in tweet-nacl (javascript) and decrypt in python

Tags: python, encryption, pynacl, tweet-nacl

This question is the inverse of the existing one here:
[Encrypt in python 3.7 and decode in NODEJS 12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63477982/encrypt-in-python-3-7-and-decode-in-nodejs-12) .

I would prefer to use the exact equivalent of *tweet-nacl* on python but that project says it is old and not recommended https://github.com/warner/python-tweetnacl . Their recommended replacement is https://github.com/pyca/pynacl : but that one is an interface to *libsodium* not *tweet-nacl* and there is no clear documentation on how to achieve the decryption.

Here is the JS encryption:

```js
    let msgArr = naclutil.decodeUTF8(jprint(msg))
    let nonce = nacl.randomBytes(nacl.box.nonceLength)
    let keyPair = this.genKeyPair()
    let encrypted = nacl.box(
      msgArr,
      nonce,
      naclutil.decodeBase64(pubKey),
      naclutil.decodeBase64(keyPair.privkey)
    )
    let nonce64 = naclutil.encodeBase64(nonce)
    let encrypted64 = naclutil.encodeBase64(encrypted)
```

The (working)  *tweet-nacl* javascript decryption code  is:

```js
  const decryptedMessage = nacl.box.open(
    naclutil.decodeBase64(payload.encrypted.encrypted),
    naclutil.decodeBase64(payload.encrypted.nonce),
    naclutil.decodeBase64(payload.encrypted.ephemPubKey),
    naclutil.decodeBase64(privKey)
  )
  const decodedMessage = naclutil.encodeUTF8(decryptedMessage)
```

My problem is that for `pynacl` they do not show any examples of using the *ephemPubKey* for decryption.  The examples I could find were like the following:

```
        import binascii
        from nacl.encoding import HexEncoder
        from nacl.exceptions import CryptoError
        from nacl.secret import Aead, SecretBox
        benc=       binascii.unhexlify(encrypted)
        bnonce =    binascii.unhexlify(nonce)
        box = SecretBox(privKey, encoder=HexEncoder)
        decrypted = box.decrypt(benc, bnonce, encoder=HexEncoder),
```

Has anyone been able to get the tweet-nacl Javascript generated encryption successfully decrypted into python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SecretBox` and thus the PyNaCl example you posted is for *symmetric* encryption, s. [here](https://pynacl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/secret/#secret-key-encryption). You can find the documentation for *public key* encryption with PyNaCl [here](https://pynacl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/public/#public-key-encryption) and for PyNaCl in general [here](https://pynacl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#).

In the following example, a plaintext is encrypted with TweetNaCl.js and decrypted with PyNaCl.

###### JavaScript side - Encryption with TweetNaCl.js:

```js
var secretKey_js  = nacl.util.decodeBase64("FJGsHP0dMkDNkpAkT4hZrcbv27L8XNO8ymhLxpPpDkE=");
var publicKey_py = nacl.util.decodeBase64("0EyrzGW6qn0EGEV0Cx2Z7tQeln6FdwZVINz0FezlvTM=");
var nonce = nacl.randomBytes(24)
var msgStr = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
var message = nacl.util.decodeUTF8(msgStr);
var box_js = nacl.box(message, nonce, publicKey_py, secretKey_js)
console.log(nacl.util.encodeBase64(nonce))  // 2e8WuEr0+5nc14VBxQrOl4ob6guOTySr
console.log(nacl.util.encodeBase64(box_js)) // eJ8sO0mFNaaWLeXVcNNpw0PurwfINp/BlnErSzOnxXJ5zqu3wLrW4fHIa4kIAxFkuMVJaf0AR4pYon0=
```

The code is basically the same as your code with the difference that the keys are not generated but imported.

###### Python side - Decryption with PyNaCl:

```py
import base64
from nacl.public import PrivateKey, PublicKey, Box
from nacl.encoding import Base64Encoder

secretKeyB64_py  = "XVdFnozXd+7xm6MVazPemgSq6un+fGpDvwgxo9UbsdM=";
publicKeyB64_js = "ixxgLis2RzqMWys76HuoH7TwrwBbXoDrwl3jGsRysRI=";

secretKey_py = PrivateKey(secretKeyB64_py, encoder=Base64Encoder)
publicKey_js = PublicKey(publicKeyB64_js, encoder=Base64Encoder)

nonce = base64.b64decode("2e8WuEr0+5nc14VBxQrOl4ob6guOTySr");
box_js = base64.b64decode("eJ8sO0mFNaaWLeXVcNNpw0PurwfINp/BlnErSzOnxXJ5zqu3wLrW4fHIa4kIAxFkuMVJaf0AR4pYon0=");

box_py = Box(secretKey_py, publicKey_js)
data = box_py.decrypt(nonce + box_js)

print(data) # b'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog'
```

---

In the example above, the keys have been imported. If a key pair needs to be generated, this is done with PyNaCl as follows:

```py
from nacl.public import PrivateKey

secretKeyNew = PrivateKey.generate()
publicKeyNew = secretKeyNew.public_key
```

---

About compatibility:
TweetNaCl.js and PyNaCl are compatible. As you described, although PyNaCl is a wrapper of Libsodium for Python (s. [here](https://pynacl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#pynacl-python-binding-to-the-libsodium-library) and [here](https://libsodium.gitbook.io/doc/bindings_for_other_languages)), but Libsodium itself is a port of NaCl (s. [here](https://libsodium.gitbook.io/doc/)), as is TweetNacl.js for JavaScript ([here](https://tweetnacl.js.org/#/)).
So ultimately, both TweetNaCl and PyNaCl are based on NaCl, the original library implemented by Bernstein *et al.*, s. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaCl_(software)), and are therefore compatible (except perhaps for a few minor syntactical differences).